# Is secure of RC6 cipher consider as weak secure? / how to increase safety in RC6 cipher?

Tags: encryption, block-cipher, symmetric

I saw a paper said RC6 cipher is weak and weakness cause of using 'SINGLE CLASS OF WEAK KEYS'
What is that mean? and could we solve this problem ?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to [cryptography.se]. Could you link to the paper that you saw?

Comment: If the question about Takeshi Shimoyama, Masahiko Takenaka, Takeshi Koshiba: [_Multiple Linear Cryptanalysis of a Reduced Round RC6_](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-45661-9_6.pdf), in proceedings of [FSE 2002](https://dopi.org/10.1007/3-540-45661-9_6) ?